# Using predefined model data in Keystonejs partials views

Tags: javascript, mongodb, keystonejs

Currently, I created a keystone model as following format:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

var SiteSettings = new keystone.List('SiteSetting', {
    map: { name: 'siteName' },
    nocreate: true,
    noedit: false,
    nodelete: true,
    singular:'SiteSetting',
    plural: 'SiteSetting',
});

SiteSettings.add({
    siteName: { type: String, required: true },
    contactNumber: { type: String, required: false },
    facebookGroupUrl: { type: String, required: false },
    googlePlusUrl: { type: String, required: false }
});

SiteSettings.register();
```

Then I went to keystone back-end, created a new Site Setting object.

And on my default template, i am using a partial view like this:

```
<body>
  <main>
    {{>header}}
    {{>footer}}
  </main>
</body>
```

And this is my footer partial:

```
<div class="row">//I want to print my site name here</div>
```

But I have no idea how can retrieve model data without a route. Because it's a partial view.

Any idea ? what should I do ? Is there anything I can do in middleware.js

Thank you everyone,.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can load the global site settings in a middleware.

```
// routes/middleware.js

exports.initLocals = (req, res, next) => {
  const { locals } = res;

  // Load site settings from db
  keystone.list('SiteSettings').model.findOne().exec((err, result) => {
    locals.siteSetting = result;
    next(err);
  });
};
```

```
// routes/index.js

const { initLocals } = require('./middleware');
keystone.pre('routes', initLocals);
```

Then you can use the `siteName` in the footer.

```
<div class="row">{{ siteSetting.siteName }}</div>
```